# Combine two tables to repeat based on row as column field sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a two tables named customer and Location for example

```
Table Customer          Table Location

Name    PartNo          Location    PartNo  maxvalue    minvalue

---------------        ---------------------------------------------

Name1   123             Location1   123     10          2
Name2   1234            Location2   1232    24          10
Name3   1232            Location2   123     14          2
                        Location1   1234    30          2
```

I need a query to display as follows

```
PartNo      Location    maxvalue    minvalue    Location    maxvalue    minvalue    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123         Location1   10          2           Location2   14          2       
1234        Location1   30          4           Location2
1232        Location1                           Location2   24          10
```

And also give a note how to extend the column field increases based on location.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: (1) What database are you using?  (2) What is the logic for the transformation?  It is not obvious to me.

Comment: In this case PartNo 123 is referenced twice, so it causes the first row in the result to have a Location/maxvalue/minvalue tuple twice.  What if you had a Location3 referencing PartNo 123, and so on and so forth.  This is essentially a recursive join, and it will be a messy output if you have a PartNo referenced by many Locations.  You need to evaluate what you are trying to accomplish.  SQL is for answering queries, not formatting.  If what you want is purely formatting the results then that should be accomplished in the end user application.

Comment: is each part certain to have no more than 2 locations? Also is there a location_id field or something of the like, on the location table?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia Right now each have only two location. Yes i do have primary field location_id. Is there any possible you can provide solution.Thanks for the reply

Comment: @AaronLS If Possible by recursive join can you provide me a sample.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Database used is Sql Server. To provide a multiple logic in a single view

Comment: @suuz How are you displaying the data to end user?

Comment: @OneZeroPundit Second code part displayed in the question session i wish to display at the end. thanks for your consideration. If possible provide me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment that there are always only up to 2 locations per part, at the most, this should get you on the right track.

If there were a field called "location_count" or something of that nature, indicating what location is "first" vs. "second", you could use conditional aggregation. Similar to how you have "location1" and "location2" in the LOCATION field now, however it is my assumption that those are location NAMES? (and not an indicator of what location is the first vs. second associated with the part).

If there were such a field you could avoid the two joins and use conditional aggregation.

In any case, given your sample data exclusively you could run the following:

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c8da/12/0

```
select x.partno,
       x.loc1,
       y.maxvalue as loc1_maxval,
       y.minvalue as loc1_minval,
       x.loc2,
       z.maxvalue as loc2_maxval,
       z.minvalue as loc2_minval
  from (select partno,
               min(location) as loc1,
               case
                 when max(location) <> min(location) then
                  max(location)
               end as loc2
          from location
         group by partno) x
  left join location y
    on x.partno = y.partno
   and x.loc1 = y.location
  left join location z
    on x.partno = z.partno
   and x.loc2 = z.location
```

**Output:**

```
| PARTNO |      LOC1 | LOC1_MAXVAL | LOC1_MINVAL |      LOC2 | LOC2_MAXVAL | LOC2_MINVAL |
|--------|-----------|-------------|-------------|-----------|-------------|-------------|
|    123 | Location1 |          10 |           2 | Location2 |          14 |           2 |
|   1232 | Location2 |          24 |           2 |    (null) |      (null) |      (null) |
|   1234 | Location1 |          30 |           2 |    (null) |      (null) |      (null) |
```

Note that parts 1232 and 1234 have only one location so they are shown in the loc1 columns. That is because they are the first and only location associated with the part. I don't understand how you are going from your sample data to have one of the locations on one side and the other on the other side. Although one has a name of "location1" and the other "location2" those values appear to be names of the locations, not an indicator of the order.

**Edit below assumes values in "LOCATION" are always "Location1" or "Location"2**

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/88f19c/1/0
This matches your expected result except the minimum for part 1234 location1 is 2 (not 4); this is consistent with your actual data.

```
select   partno,
         'Location1' as location1,
         max(case location when 'Location1' then maxvalue end) as l1_max,
         max(case location when 'Location1' then minvalue end) as l1_min,
         'Location2' as location2,
         max(case location when 'Location2' then maxvalue end) as l2_max,
         max(case location when 'Location2' then minvalue end) as l2_min
from     location
group by partno
```

**Output:**

```
| PARTNO | LOCATION1 | L1_MAX | L1_MIN | LOCATION2 | L2_MAX | L2_MIN |
|--------|-----------|--------|--------|-----------|--------|--------|
|    123 | Location1 |     10 |      2 | Location2 |     14 |      2 |
|   1232 | Location1 | (null) | (null) | Location2 |     24 |     10 |
|   1234 | Location1 |     30 |      2 | Location2 | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts.But not able to get the above result.There was flaw in question now i have corrected the above result to display. sorry for the inconvenience caused by me.

Comment: @suuz Although the NAME of that location is "location 2", what actually indicates it is the 'second' location? That appears to be just a name, as though some other row might show 'Alabama' as the location. Is there a "LOCATION_NUM" field that shows 1 or 2? Or, are ALL of the location values either location1/location2? It is unclear if that is a location name field or a location # field.

Comment: @suuz If all of your values in the "LOCATION" column are ALWAYS "Location1" or "Location2" the query I just added to my answer probably does what you want.